# doubly linked list of numbers with 2 structs

Tags: c

I'm trying to figure out how to write the below Code with Doubly Linked List.

The user will be asked to enter a number. If the number is negative should be added at the beginning and if it is positive in the end. The program will be stopped when the user enter 0 .

I must use the below predefined Structs.

I'm little bit confused because of using "typedef struct Node* NodePtr;" and then NodePtr in both structs. Could someone explain to me what is the proper way of thinking here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef struct Node* NodePtr; /* Pointer to a node */

typedef struct Node     /* Node contains a read number */
{
    int n;          /* Stored number */
    NodePtr prev;
    NodePtr next; 
} Knoten;

typedef struct
{ /* Structure for double linked lists: start + end */
    NodePtr start;      /* Pointer to the beginning of the doubly linked list */
    NodePtr end;        /* Pointer to the end of the doubly linked list */
} DVListe;
```

---

Here is what I have so far. Ofcourse there are alot of errors and segmentation faults :)

I still can't understand where to define the start and end and to whom should I assign them, newNode or NodePtr or something totally different than that? :/

```
 // continue
    DVList *h = NULL;
    Knoten *newNode;

    void negative_start(int n)
    {
        if (newNode == NULL)
        {
            newNode = malloc(sizeof(Knoten));
            if (newNode == NULL)
            {
                printf("ERROR! Could not allocate memory");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            newNode->n = n;
            newNode->prev = NULL;
            newNode->next = NULL;

            newNode = h->start;
            h->start = h->end;
        }
        else
        {
            newNode = malloc (sizeof(Knoten));
            if (newNode == NULL)
                {
                    printf("ERROR! Could not allocate memory");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
            newNode->n = n;
            newNode->next = h->start;
            newNode->prev = NULL;
            h->start = newNode;
        }
    }
    void positive_end(int n)
    {
        // I didn't write it because it will be wrong like the negative_start function.
    }

    int main ()
    {
        int x;
        newNode = NULL;
        printf("\n Enter a number ");
        scanf("%d", &x);
        while ( x != 0)
        {
            if ( x < 0 ){ negative_start(x); 
                        }
            else{ positive_end(x); 
                }
            scanf("%d", &x);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

---

I've tried to write the code from new with @ChrisTurner structs.

It's working only with negative numbers. If I entered any positive numbers only, they will be discarded. Can someone please help me with this one?

```html
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef struct Node Knoten;
typedef struct DVListe_s DVList;

struct Node
{
    int n;
    Knoten *next;
    Knoten *prev;
};

struct DVListe_s
{
    Knoten *start;
    Knoten *end;
};

DVList *construct()
{
    DVList *list;
    list = malloc (sizeof(DVList));
    list->start = NULL;
    list->end = NULL;
    
    return list;
}



void add_negative_start (DVList *list, int n)
{
    if (list->start != NULL)
    {
        Knoten *newNode = malloc(sizeof(Knoten));
        newNode->prev = NULL;
        newNode->next = NULL;
        newNode->n = n;
        
        newNode->next = list->start;
        list->start = newNode;
    }
     else
    {
        Knoten *newNode = malloc(sizeof(Knoten));
        newNode->prev = NULL;
        newNode->next = NULL;
        newNode->n = n;
        
        list->start = newNode;
        list->end = list->start;
    }
}

void add_positive_end(DVList *list, int n)
{
    if (list->end != NULL)
    {
        Knoten *newNode = malloc(sizeof(Knoten));
        newNode->prev = NULL;
        newNode->next = NULL;
        newNode->n = n;
        
        newNode->prev = list->end;
        list->end = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        Knoten *newNode = malloc(sizeof(Knoten));
        newNode->prev = NULL;
        newNode->next = NULL;
        newNode->n = n;
        
        list->end = newNode;
        list->start = list->end;
    }
}

void print(DVList *list)
{
    Knoten *temp = list->start;
    printf ("Entered Numbers\n");
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\n", temp->n);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    DVList *list = construct();
    
    int x = 1;
    printf("Enter a number\n");
    
    while (x)
    {
        scanf ("%d", &x);
        if (x < 0)
        {
            add_negative_start(list, x);
        }
        else
        {
            add_positive_end(list, x);
        }
          
    }
    print(list);
    
    return 0;
}
 R
```

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: what did you tried so far? can you show us some code, so that we can find the reason why it does not work correctly. at least you can show us the code of your main and how you would try to use these structs

Comment: I think you should study something about pointers and linked list before to try understand the code, that is very clear with comments

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Did you get up on the wrong side of the bed this morning? ;)

Comment: Thank you for your answeres. This is not Homework, just practicing with old Exams from my uni. My question is with the pointers itself. I'm confused how to use the NodePtr, since it's used inside both of the structs.

Comment: Do not `typedef` pointers, it will only serve to confuse the sh.. out of you any anyone else who has to work with your code. When you `typedef` a pointer you are hiding one-level of indirection. While it may save having to add a dereference character in parameter lists, the confusion it causes is rarely if ever worth it.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin well understood :)  this was an exam question from last summer, so I think I have to deal with it -.-

Answer (score 0):

`typedef` creates what could be thought of as an alias between `NodePtr` and `struct Node *` so that whenever you put `NodePtr` the compiler knows you actually meant `struct Node *`.

You can't use `struct NodePtr` inside `struct NodePtr` because at that point it doesn't know how big `struct NodePtr` is, so whether or not you use a `typedef` you do need to use pointers at this point.

In your `DVListe`, because your list will start off empty, you use pointers here so that you can set `start` and `end` to `NULL` to indicate that or if you have one node, that they can both point at the same place.

Personally I don't think creating a `typedef` to a pointer of something is overly a good idea, although you are at least making it clear that it's a pointer with the name. You could lose that `typedef` and do it like this also.

```
typedef struct Node Knoten;
typedef struct DVListe_s DVListe;

struct Node     /* Node contains a read number */
{
    int n;          /* Stored number */
    Node *prev;
    Node *next; 
};

struct DVListe_s
{ /* Structure for double linked lists: start + end */
    Node *start;      /* Pointer to the beginning of the doubly linked list */
    Node *end;        /* Pointer to the end of the doubly linked list */
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will try again to write the whole code in both ways and I will post them down.